# How do i Check if a xml Sibling has attributes?

Tags: c#, xml, siblings

My program is doing weird stuff if i delete one of my Attributes because it is not able to handle Siblings without Attributes. Now i googled for a while but i am not able to find a good way to check for attributes.

Whats the way you prefer checking for attributes?

```
while (FXMLNode != null)
{
     if (FXMLNode.Name.ToLower() == "datei")
     {
           xmlInformationen oInfo = new xmlInformationen();
           oInfo.Dateipfad = FXMLNode.InnerText;

           if (FXMLNode.Attributes["checked"].Value.ToString() == "true")
                oInfo.CheckBox = true;
           else if (FXMLNode.Attributes["checked"].Value.ToString() == "false")
                oInfo.CheckBox = false;
           else if(FXMLNode == null)
                oInfo.CheckBox = true;
           else
                oInfo.CheckBox = true;

           lstAttribute.Add(oInfo);
           iCounter++;

           if (FXMLNode.NextSibling == null)
           {
                FXMLNode = FXMLNode.FirstChild;
           }
           else
           {
                FXMLNode = FXMLNode.NextSibling;
           }
      }
      else
      {
           if (FXMLNode.NextSibling == null)
           {
                FXMLNode = FXMLNode.FirstChild;
           }
           else
           {
                FXMLNode = FXMLNode.NextSibling;
           }
      }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid we need a bit more information. Some source code would be nice.

Comment: The following code is a part of the function where i read the XML and the attributes itself. I have to place the Attribute-check somewhere there.

Comment: Just edited the code part to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing the value of an attribute without knowing if the attribute exists or not. Rewrite your code to check for the attribute first:

```
oInfo.CheckBox = true;
if(FXMLNode == null) oInfo.CheckBox = true; //not sure why you set it to true here
else if (FXMLNode.HasAttribute("checked"))
{
     if (FXMLNode.Attributes["checked"].Value.ToString() == "true")
            oInfo.CheckBox = true;
     else if (FXMLNode.Attributes["checked"].Value.ToString() == "false")
            oInfo.CheckBox = false;
}
```

Please note that checking if the Xml element is `null` should be the first thing you do. If it's `null` then it surely won't have any attributes but you'll have an exception.

Comment: I set it to true because its part of the module a customer wants to have. So thats wanted :) Thanks for your help, i will try that now. //edit:: i would love to give you an upvote but im to new, sorry mate.

Answer (score 0):

you can just check thats the attribute in not null like this

```
if (FXMLNode.Attributes["checked"]!=null)
```

and then check the value